# recurrence relation of the dynamic programming to get the maximum credits

Tags: dynamic-programming

My problem is I have a fixed time and I must get the highest profit.
How can I write  recurrence relation for a dynamic program?

An example for my problem:
The times are `[3, 2, 4, 2, 1]`
The profits are `[20, 15, 20, 25, 20]`
The requested hours are `6`

The answer should be `65` by picking the times with indices `0,3,4` that have profit `20 + 25 + 20 = 65`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets define the function `f(i,h)` that gives the maximum profit for exactly h hours from the profits with indices(0,1,2...,i), then the result for your case is `f(size_of_the_array , number_of_hours) = f(5,6)`.

The main recurrence formula will be like this:

```
f(i,h) = max(w1,w2);
w1 = f(i-1,h); //don't consider the i-th profit in the sum
w2 = f(i-1,h-time[i]) + profit[i]; : h>=time[i] //consider the i-th profit in the sum
```

This is similar to a standard problem in dynamic programming called [0-1Knapsack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/)

you can study it first, then your question will be easy to solve.